# The Notes App is now gone from my Macbook Air. How do I get it back?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, notes.app

The Notes app is now gone from my Macbook Air. It used to be in the doc and sync'd with my iPhone and iPad. Earlier today, I saw the icon still there, with a question mark on top of it, and I could not open the app. Now, there is just a question mark. How do I get the Notes App back on my Macbook Air?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get back a system file after deleting it from my Mac?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/how-can-i-get-back-a-system-file-after-deleting-it-from-my-mac)

Comment: @grgarside This isn't really a system file since it resides in the /Application folder, no?

Comment: @bmike Apps that are part of OS X in /Applications are included in the list you edited in to the question and the answers provided there do answer this question including reinstall/Pacifist/another Mac.

Comment: @grgarside I'm not sure where to draw the line, clearly.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do might be to check in Lauchpad (the silver rocket in the dock or in /Applications ) to search for notes.

If it's still there, it just got moved, so you can search in Spotlight to find it.

If it's really gone, you can restore it using Time Machine or another backup. Worst case, you would have to re-install the OS but that might need some details about how you purchased Mountain Lion (whether it was an upgrade or came with the Mac for instance).

Comment: It is not in Launchpad (the silver rocket) or the sub folder, and I also checked in /appliaitons, not there. grrr. so it's really gone somehow. Maddening. If I reinstalled the OS, would I lose all the applications I have installed? (I believe I paid for it through iTunes).

Comment: No - when you reinstall the OS, it won't write older versions of apps that are already installed. What did you pay for in iTunes? The notes app from Apple is free on iOS and OSX.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark on the app means that the app cannot be found. Since the Dock *should* follow to a new location automatically if the app was moved, it *usually* means that the app has been deleted (if the app was in the Trash, a separate error should show).

1. ### Use a backup

   If you have a backup such as Time Machine available, attempt to recover the file from there. This should be the easiest method if you have your backup readily available.

   Navigate to the `/Applications` folder, open Time Machine, go back in time until you find `Notes.app`, select it and click **Restore**.
2. ### Use another Mac with the same OS X version

   If you have access to another Mac with the exact same OS X version, you should be able to copy the app from that machine and put it in the `/Applications` folder on your Mac with the missing app.
3. ### Use Pacifist with an OS X installer

   If you have access to an OS X installer, whether that be on disc or USB, you can use Pacifist to browse through and obtain the file.

   [image]

   If you don't have access to an installation media, you can download the installer from the Mac App Store.

   [image]
4. ### Reinstall OS X

   If all else fails, a reinstallation of OS X will restore all default Apps.