# Can I Reinstall iBooks?

Tags: macos, books

So I accidently removed iBooks from my installation. Is it possible to reinstall that app again without reinstalling Mavericks?

If so, how?

Comment: Could we make sure that you really lost the app? Did you check your trash? Or maybe you just renamed it by accident, so what exactly did you do to delete it?

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/how-can-i-get-back-a-system-file-after-deleting-it-from-my-mac

Comment: I shift+backspaced it. Emptied the trash and it's been gone for several weeks. It cannot be found by Alfred App or Spotlight. It cannot be opened from within iTunes. It is gone! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Copy the file from another system or a trusted person's machine

If you have a second machine with a comparable build of OS X installed on it, you can copy the file from it. Feel free to ask for the checksum of a file in chat to compare it to if you wish to make sure that the file is correct (not modified accidentally/purposefully).

#### Pacifist with OS X install media

If you've got an OS X install media and [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/), you can browse the install media and grab the file.

[image]

If you have Pacifist but no install media, it will prompt you to download the installer.

[image]

Comment: This helped me. I didn't realize I could simply copy the app from another mac. Worked like a charm! :)