# How to reinstall iBooks on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, books

I have Macbook Pro Retina with Mavericks. Somehow I uninstalled iBooks. How can I re-install it? I tried Google but did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it from Mac App Store. Just open it, search for iBooks and enter your Apple ID credentials when prompted.

Comment: There is no iBooks in App Store.

Comment: My bad. It comes preinstalled on Maverick. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116807/can-i-reinstall-ibooks