# Java - Mistakenly removed /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions

Tags: macos, java

Using Mountation Lion, I've mistakenly removed all of the content in `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions`
How can I get java working again on my machine? (I don't have it in Trash)

Also worth noting, I do have /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk

UPDATE: I ended up upgrading to Mavericks.

Comment: Have you tried downloading it again here?https://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp

Comment: @dennismuys, Yes, I'm getting 'The installation failed' message without too much detail.

Comment: We have a "canonical" question that covers your options in pretty good detail. Please edit your question to explain why/how that doesn't get you out of your situation and this can easily be reopened for an answer that doesn't fit he generic case. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/how-can-i-get-back-a-system-file-after-deleting-it-from-my-mac

Comment: @bmike, unfortunately, there is no //System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/ in the Base System mount.

Comment: Yes, but you have reinstall, backup, get from another Mac options all in that thread. However if you edit your post to explain why you can't fix it or won't fix it using some / all of the steps outlined, this post will get reviewed for reopening.