# After using a virus scanner to clean my Mac, it will no longer start

Tags: macos, startup

I had been getting a lot of pop-ups and browser ads on my Mac and I suspected it might be due to a virus so I installed Avast. After running a virus scan, Avast found 10 viruses and 18 warnings, which I told it to delete.

It might have deleted some system files because now my mac will not start. If shows the Apple logo on boot and then it shows an error logo with the processing bar and that's as far as it ever gets.

Please tell me how I can get my Mac back in to a working state?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get back a system file after deleting it from my Mac?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/how-can-i-get-back-a-system-file-after-deleting-it-from-my-mac). If the answers to this existing question do not fix your problem, please expand your question.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside I don't think a non-boot matches the canonical question since we would at least need to explain what files and folders precicely need to be restored as well as whether there is a Recovery HD here and if the OP knows if it's functional.

Answer (score 1):

Since we do not know what was deleted, I suggest you

Press Command-R during startup

That will start from the OS X Recovery System

to repair your OS.