# Reinstall assembler, /usr/bin/as

Tags: install, xcode, recovery

I've lost /usr/bin/as. How does one reinstall it?

There's no as in the /usr/bin of my recovery partition. Reinstalling XCode and command line tools didn't help. I haven't been successful compiling gas from source because I get a linking error. (Is the default in fact gas?)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24308125/linking-errors-and-bfd-bfd-gnu-binutils-2-24-assertion-fail

I suspect that the gas program I'm trying to compile might solve the compiling problems I'm having but that does me no good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a copy of [/usr/bin/as from OS X 10.9.4](http://georgegarside.com/o/se/files-osx-10-9-4/as).

With regard to how you'd actually get it back, you might be able to extract it from the install media if you have it or by reinstalling the OS. See [How can I get back a system file after deleting it from my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/how-can-i-get-back-a-system-file-after-deleting-it-from-my-mac)