# How to restore a removed /bin/sh file?

Tags: macos, file

I have followed a guide online which requested me to run this command:

```
sudo cp /opt/local/bin/node /bin/sh
```

It was a guide for fixing LESS. Instead of fixing it, it only made it worse. I have lost the file.

Is there any way to recover/refetch this file, or could someone upload their `sh` file for me?

Comment: To request someone to upload their `sh` for you is as risky as it was to follow the receipe you did.
This is **trust at random** :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run this command to copy /bin/sh from the BaseSystem.dmg on the Recovery HD:

```
diskutil mount Recovery\ HD &&
    hdiutil mount /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/BaseSystem.dmg &&
    sudo cp -p /Volumes/OS\ X\ Base\ System/bin/sh /bin/sh
```

Also see [How can I get back a system file after deleting it from my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/116612/)

Answer (score 1):

`/bin/sh` is actually a lot easier to fix if you have read through something like *Linux from Scratch* as it is usually a symlink on other UNIXes, pointing to a shell, usually `/bin/bash`, and occasionally `/bin/dash`.

The quick and fix:

```
sudo ln -sf bash /bin/sh
```

as it will create a symlink pointing from `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash` just like every other UNIX and Linux distribution. You can of course symlink it to any other Bourne-compatible shells you would like to use, including that latest `bash-4.3` or even Debian's `dash`.