# How to restore default system files?

Tags: macos, restore, themes

Does anyone have the default SArtFile.bin (path: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SArtFile.bin) for Mavericks 10.9.5?

I was tinkering around with the file listed above but forgot to  back it up.
Does anyone know how I can restore the file to its original form so I can undo my changes, or how to restore default system files?

Comment: reinstall the combo update of the OS - also which ones there are several - i.e. you should give the app they are ion

Comment: I don't want to reinstall OS X. I only want the actual files. Thanks.

Comment: reinstall is the easiest way

Comment: how do you reinstall the combo update without losing files?

Comment: The update will only change the OSs files which you should not have changed - if you have then you need to know how to get them back before you do - i.e. you should be proficient in Unix first - that will include knowing how to restore you backups

Comment: I reinstalled the combo update. It didn't fix the problem :(

Comment: What are the full paths of those files?

Comment: The paths to these files are: /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/ArtFile.bin

Answer (score 2):

This is a specific case of the general restore process:

- [How can I get back a system file after deleting it from my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/how-can-i-get-back-a-system-file-after-deleting-it-from-my-mac)

Basically you have three places where you can get the original system files (except backups):

- Recovery HD
- Combo update installer
- the (Mac) OS X installer

---

The Recovery HD is a basic OS X system only and just contains a subset of the files of the full system. Some files may even be outdated or different compared to the files of the full system. To mount the Recovery HD enter `diskutil mount Recovery\ HD` in Terminal. To get access to the system files mount *BaseSystem.dmg*:

```
hdiutil mount /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/BaseSystem.dmg
```

To copy a file enter:

```
sudo cp /Volumes/Mac\ OS\ X\ Base\ System/path/to/file /path/to/file
```

in your example:

```
sudo cp /Volumes/Mac\ OS\ X\ Base\ System/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SArtFile.bin /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources/SArtFile.bin
```

---

The Combo update installer may contain the file in question. Like the Recovery HD it only contains a subset of files of the full OS X system. To extract and install the original file, download [Pacifist](https://www.charlessoft.com/) and open the installer package. Search for the file in question and install it. You need admin privileges to do that.

---

If the file isn't available in the Recovery HD or the Combo installer you have to download the newest OS X installer (in your case *Install OS X Mavericks* (10.9.5)). The approach is similar to the Combo updater method. Right-click *Install OS X Mavericks* -> Show Contents, navigate to /Contents/SharedSupport and mount the InstallESD.dmg. Open the folder *Packages* in the mounted image and then the file *OSInstall.mpkg* with Pacifist. Search for the file in question and install it. You need admin privileges to do that.

---

In your case you are lucky because the file *SArtFile.bin* can be found in the Recovery HD. So use the method outlined above to recover the file.

Answer (score -1):

updating & re-installation OS X without formating is keep your files. It's not a windows where all your file puts in to Windows.old and later you need go for folders take them from there.