# Do I need to reinstall OS X after accidentally removing Python?

Tags: macos, install, python

I managed to delete my python in `usr/bin` by foolishly doing `sudo rm /usr/bin/python` and now it seems like I need to reinstall my OS.

First off is this necessary? And secondly is there an easy way to do this without having to erase everything on my disk?

In other words ideally I would like my programs I have installed to remain there after reboot saving me the trouble of having to install everything again to date. Is this possible?

Comment: I assume you don't have a (Time Machine) backup?

Comment: Not on this machine unfortunately

Comment: I guess [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/116611/45492) solves your problem. @fartheraway: It does, unless you exclude them.

Comment: I stand corrected

Comment: Are you sure you need to reinstall the OS? Have you tried installing the full version of Python? https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/

Comment: No I wasn't sure but after digging around some of the forums and responses it seems like the Python I deleted is the one that is used by the OS and as such 'breaks' it. I'm not sure if these can be replaced by an ordinary Python installation. In any case it was a problem easily solved!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/116611/45492) probably has all the answers for you. In short there is no easy way. Your options are:

1. Recover the files from a (Time machin) Backup, if existent.
2. Reinstall OSX, e.g. from the Recovery mode pressing  <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at the startup screen
3. Copy the missing files from the Recovery partition (check if the partition is up to date first). E.g. by doing `cp -a /bin /Volumes/<your disk name>`

Answer (score 1):

If it's only one file you need, you can DL your version of OS X, and create a USB installer. Then install the new OS X on another flash drive. This one is called a bootable flash drive. Then go back to your troubled system and mount the bootable drive. Find the file you need and voila.

Comment: Thanks. But it seems easier to just reinstall OS X by restarting and then cmd+R to get to OS X utilities screen. By selecting 'reinstall a new copy of OS X' will this just change the system and leave my installations alone?

Comment: If by "my installations" u mean your apps? My guess is no. Migration tools only show up in an upgrade. Doing it ur way might wipe Everything clean. Back up should u try.

Comment: I mean for example some programs I have installed from source on my system. I'm guessing not.

Comment: @Jack , the reinstall with cmd-r is the way to go. It reinstalls in place - leaves all your 'extras' (applications, settings, etc). I'd still backup to time machine first - but I've had to run the reinstall, and was very pleased with the results (and didn't have to use my time machine backup at all).