# Report Crash ~350% CPU Yosemite

Tags: macos, crash, activity-monitor, cpu

10.10.3

There is a process, I do not know how its started and what it starts, which uses ~350% of the CPU. Its performed by 'root'. When I quit it from the activity monitor it comes back straight away.

Any ideas?

```
Process:               locationd [2129]
Path:                  /usr/libexec/locationd
Identifier:            locationd
Version:               1615.24
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
Responsible:           locationd [2129]
User ID:               205

PlugIn Path:             /usr/libexec/locationd
PlugIn Identifier:       locationd
PlugIn Version:          ??? (1615.24)

Date/Time:             2015-06-01 15:07:26.317 +0200
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.3 (14D136)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        ****


Time Awake Since Boot: 1400 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000032, 0x000000010804a000

kernel messages:
-0 sec              CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x10804a000): p=2129[locationd] final status 0x3004a00, denying page sending SIGKILL
-4 sec              CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x10c5f1000): p=2126[locationd] final status 0x3004a00, denying page sending SIGKILL
-4 sec              CODE SIGNING: process 2126[locationd]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x10c5f1000 from offset 0x48f000 in file "/usr/libexec/locationd" (cs_mtime:1419277632.0 == mtime:1419277632.0) (signed:1 validated:1 tainted:1 wpmapped:0 slid:0)
-8 sec              CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x10dbca000): p=2119[locationd] final status 0x3004a00, denying page sending SIGKILL
-8 sec              CODE SIGNING: process 2119[locationd]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x10dbca000 from offset 0x48f000 in file "/usr/libexec/locationd" (cs_mtime:1419277632.0 == mtime:1419277632.0) (signed:1 validated:1 tainted:1 wpmapped:0 slid:0)
-11 sec             CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x10d9ed000): p=2115[locationd] final status 0x3004a00, denying page sending SIGKILL
-11 sec             CODE SIGNING: process 2115[locationd]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x10d9ed000 from offset 0x48f000 in file "/usr/libexec/locationd" (cs_mtime:1419277632.0 == mtime:1419277632.0) (signed:1 validated:1 tainted:1 wpmapped:0 slid:0)
-15 sec             CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x107f61000): p=2112[locationd] final status 0x3004a00, denying page sending SIGKILL
-15 sec             CODE SIGNING: process 2112[locationd]: rejecting invalid page at address 0x107f61000 from offset 0x48f000 in file "/usr/libexec/locationd" (cs_mtime:1419277632.0 == mtime:1419277632.0) (signed:1 validated:1 tainted:1 wpmapped:0 slid:0)
-18 sec             CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x10bff4000): p=2106[locationd] final status 0x3004a00, denying page sending SIGKILL

VM Regions Near 0x10804a000:
    __DATA                 0000000108042000-000000010804a000 [   32K] rw-/rwx SM=NUL  /usr/libexec/locationd
--> __LINKEDIT             000000010804a000-000000010806b000 [  132K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /usr/libexec/locationd
    __LINKEDIT             000000010806b000-000000010806c000 [    4K] r--/rwx SM=NUL  /usr/libexec/locationd

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
/usr/libexec/locationd

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                            0x00007fff6af4b11d ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::rebase(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 205
1   dyld                            0x00007fff6af42f94 ImageLoader::recursiveRebase(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 126
2   dyld                            0x00007fff6af4270c ImageLoader::link(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, bool, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 144
3   dyld                            0x00007fff6af38be4 dyld::link(ImageLoader*, bool, bool, ImageLoader::RPathChain const&) + 166
4   dyld                            0x00007fff6af39a87 dyld::_main(macho_header const*, unsigned long, int, char const**, char const**, char const**, unsigned long*) + 2370
5   dyld                            0x00007fff6af35276 dyldbootstrap::start(macho_header const*, int, char const**, long, macho_header const*, unsigned long*) + 512
6   dyld                            0x00007fff6af35036 _dyld_start + 54

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000010804c380  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000107bb3000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x000000010804c380  rsi: 0x000000010804c380  rbp: 0x00007fff5804c310  rsp: 0x00007fff5804c260
   r8: 0x000000010804a000   r9: 0x0000000107bb3000  r10: 0x000000010804c380  r11: 0x000000010804c380
  r12: 0x000000010804a000  r13: 0x00007fff6af723d8  r14: 0x0000000007bb3000  r15: 0x00007fff6af5eb17
  rip: 0x00007fff6af4b11d  rfl: 0x0000000000010246  cr2: 0x000000010804a000

Logical CPU:     0
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x107bb3000 -        0x107ff7fff  locationd (1615.24) <E6A1B272-5762-3F69-9D0B-E046A930DD6B> /usr/libexec/locationd
    0x7fff6af34000 -     0x7fff6af6a837  dyld (353.2.1) <65DCCB06-339C-3E25-9702-600A28291D0E> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff86467000 -     0x7fff864b4ff7  com.apple.print.framework.PrintCore (10.3 - 451.1) <DE992474-0841-38A1-B4F6-46D653E454D5> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/PrintCore.framework/Versions/A/PrintCore
    0x7fff864b5000 -     0x7fff864d2ffb  libresolv.9.dylib (57) <26B38E61-298A-3C3A-82C1-3B5E98AD5E29> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x7fff864d3000 -     0x7fff86926fc7  com.apple.vImage (8.0 - 8.0) <33BE7B31-72DB-3364-B37E-C322A32748C5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fff86e53000 -     0x7fff86e54fff  com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent (2.0 - 25) <2D61A2C3-C83E-3A3F-8EC1-736DBEC250AB> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TrustEvaluationAgent.framework/Versions/A/TrustEvaluationAgent
    0x7fff86e5a000 -     0x7fff86e61fff  com.apple.NetFS (6.0 - 4.0) <1581D25F-CC07-39B0-90E8-5D4F3CF84EBA> /System/Library/Frameworks/NetFS.framework/Versions/A/NetFS
    0x7fff86e62000 -     0x7fff86ea8ff7  libFontRegistry.dylib (134.1) <CE41D8C2-BEED-345C-BC4F-3775CC06C672> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontRegistry.dylib
    0x7fff86eae000 -     0x7fff86f1afff  com.apple.framework.CoreWLAN (5.0 - 500.35.2) <5E228544-77A9-3AA5-8355-E8F6626F50E7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreWLAN.framework/Versions/A/CoreWLAN
    0x7fff86f2f000 -     0x7fff86f30ffb  libremovefile.dylib (35) <3485B5F4-6CE8-3C62-8DFD-8736ED6E8531> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x7fff86f31000 -     0x7fff86f98ff7  com.apple.framework.CoreWiFi (3.0 - 300.4) <19269C1D-EB29-384A-83F3-7DDDEB7D9DAD> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreWiFi.framework/Versions/A/CoreWiFi
    0x7fff8701c000 -     0x7fff87094ff7  com.apple.SystemConfiguration (1.14 - 1.14) <06A8405D-53BA-30A9-BA8A-222099176091> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
    0x7fff87095000 -     0x7fff8709affb  libheimdal-asn1.dylib (398.10.1) <A7B6447A-6680-3625-83C3-993B58D5C43F> /usr/lib/libheimdal-asn1.dylib
    0x7fff8709b000 -     0x7fff873ccfff  com.apple.Foundation (6.9 - 1153.20) <F0FF3A5D-C5B7-34A1-9319-DE1EF928E58E> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    0x7fff87547000 -     0x7fff87554fff  libxar.1.dylib (255) <7CD69BB5-97BA-3858-8A8B-2F33F129E6E7> /usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib
    0x7fff87555000 -     0x7fff875c4fff  com.apple.SearchKit (1.4.0 - 1.4.0) <80883BD1-C9BA-3794-A20E-476F94DD89A9> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SearchKit.framework/Versions/A/SearchKit
    0x7fff87636000 -     0x7fff87668ff3  com.apple.frameworks.CoreDaemon (1.3 - 1.3) <C6DB0A07-F8E4-3837-BCA9-225F460EDA81> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDaemon.framework/Versions/B/CoreDaemon
    0x7fff87708000 -     0x7fff8770eff7  libsystem_networkextension.dylib (167.1.10) <29AB225B-D7FB-30ED-9600-65D44B9A9442> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
    0x7fff8770f000 -     0x7fff8771afff  libcommonCrypto.dylib (60061) <D381EBC6-69D8-31D3-8084-5A80A32CB748> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
    0x7fff881d1000 -     0x7fff88243fff  com.apple.framework.IOKit (2.0.2 - 1050.20.2) <09C0518C-90DF-3FC3-96D6-34D35F72C8EF> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
    0x7fff88244000 -     0x7fff8825fff7  com.apple.aps.framework (4.0 - 4.0) <5F4CEDD6-C7AD-3026-A5F3-9146F08F23D2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/Versions/A/ApplePushService
    0x7fff88263000 -     0x7fff88268ff7  libmacho.dylib (862) <126CA2ED-DE91-308F-8881-B9DAEC3C63B6> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x7fff88296000 -     0x7fff882eafff  libc++.1.dylib (120) <1B9530FD-989B-3174-BB1C-BDC159501710> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x7fff88383000 -     0x7fff8838bff3  com.apple.CoreServices.FSEvents (1210.20.1 - 1210.20.1) <84F79D3E-7B5E-3C93-8479-35794A3F125E> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/FSEvents.framework/Versions/A/FSEvents
    0x7fff883ba000 -     0x7fff883c3ff3  com.apple.CommonAuth (4.0 - 2.0) <BA9F5A09-D200-3D18-9F4A-20C789291A30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonAuth.framework/Versions/A/CommonAuth
    0x7fff883c4000 -     0x7fff883c6fff  libRadiance.dylib (1237) <8F1E898B-74F6-3242-B929-CAF58AFCE319> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libRadiance.dylib
    0x7fff88401000 -     0x7fff88410fff  com.apple.LangAnalysis (1.7.0 - 1.7.0) <D1E527E4-C561-352F-9457-E8C50232793C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LangAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/LangAnalysis
    0x7fff8908c000 -     0x7fff89373ffb  com.apple.CoreServices.CarbonCore (1108.6 - 1108.6) <8953580E-7857-33B2-AA64-98296830D3A8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
    0x7fff893bb000 -     0x7fff893bbfff  libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib (162.1) <E0605012-0DDB-3150-8FD0-699376FA3CD0> /usr/lib/libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib
    0x7fff893bc000 -     0x7fff893c9ff3  com.apple.ProtocolBuffer (1 - 228.0.1) <3429EB06-9F0E-355F-B9AB-F72879177398> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/Versions/A/ProtocolBuffer
    0x7fff893ca000 -     0x7fff893f3ffb  libxslt.1.dylib (13) <AED1143F-B848-3E73-81ED-71356F25F084> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x7fff89424000 -     0x7fff89465fff  libGLU.dylib (11.1.2) <4C54F0D1-2ADC-38A0-92D1-F479E9B99355> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLU.dylib
    0x7fff89466000 -     0x7fff8957fffb  com.apple.CoreText (352.0 - 454.6) <D45790B0-E1A3-3C7D-8BA2-AB71D2CFA7FB> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
    0x7fff8966b000 -     0x7fff89670fff  com.apple.DiskArbitration (2.6 - 2.6) <0DFF4D9B-2AC3-3B82-B5C5-30F4EFBD2DB9> /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
    0x7fff89739000 -     0x7fff8982dfff  libFontParser.dylib (134.2) <9F57B025-AB9C-31DD-9D54-2D7AB1298885> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libFontParser.dylib
    0x7fff8982e000 -     0x7fff89866fff  libsystem_network.dylib (412.20.3) <589A5F67-BE2A-3245-A181-0ECC9B53EB00> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x7fff898fa000 -     0x7fff89902ff7  com.apple.AppleSRP (5.0 - 1) <01EC5144-D09A-3D6A-AE35-F6D48585F154> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/Versions/A/AppleSRP
    0x7fff89903000 -     0x7fff8998fff7  libsystem_c.dylib (1044.10.1) <86FBED7A-F2C8-3591-AD6F-486DD57E6B6A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x7fff89ae0000 -     0x7fff89c22fff  libsqlite3.dylib (168) <7B580EB9-9260-35FE-AE2F-276A2C242BAB> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x7fff89d8e000 -     0x7fff89d8efff  com.apple.CoreServices (62 - 62) <C69DA8A7-B536-34BF-A93F-1C170E2C6D58> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    0x7fff89f00000 -     0x7fff89f09fff  libGFXShared.dylib (11.1.2) <0BAF2EA8-3BC4-3BF4-ABB6-A6E0A1F3F6A5> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x7fff89f0a000 -     0x7fff89f64ff7  com.apple.LanguageModeling (1.0 - 1) <ACA93FE0-A0E3-333E-AE3C-8EB7DE5F362F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/Versions/A/LanguageModeling
    0x7fff89f65000 -     0x7fff89f67fff  libsystem_configuration.dylib (699.1.5) <20F3B077-179D-3CB0-A3C1-C8602D53B4DB> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x7fff89fa1000 -     0x7fff89fbbfff  com.apple.AppleVPAFramework (1.4.3 - 1.4.3) <AE62A92E-EDA7-37AD-8AF0-7912E9381A1F> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleVPA.framework/Versions/A/AppleVPA
    0x7fff89fbc000 -     0x7fff89fd9fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (2782.20.48) <EAFD7BD0-0C30-3E7D-9528-F9916BA0167C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff8a0b6000 -     0x7fff8a44eff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1153.18) <5C0892B8-9691-341F-9279-CA3A74D59AA0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    0x7fff8a44f000 -     0x7fff8a457ffb  libcopyfile.dylib (118.1.2) <0C68D3A6-ACDD-3EF3-991A-CC82C32AB836> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x7fff8a4b6000 -     0x7fff8a4befff  libsystem_platform.dylib (63) <64E34079-D712-3D66-9CE2-418624A5C040> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x7fff8a6b9000 -     0x7fff8a7ddff7  com.apple.LaunchServices (644.56 - 644.56) <20AABB1C-9319-3E4D-A024-51B0DD5FCD3B> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/LaunchServices
    0x7fff8a93d000 -     0x7fff8a947ff7  com.apple.NetAuth (5.2 - 5.2) <2BBD749A-8E18-35B8-8E48-A90347C1CCA7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetAuth.framework/Versions/A/NetAuth
    0x7fff8a948000 -     0x7fff8a963ff7  libCRFSuite.dylib (34) <D64842BE-7BD4-3D0C-9842-1D202F7C2A51> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
    0x7fff8a964000 -     0x7fff8ac97ff7  libmecabra.dylib (666.7) <0ED8AE5E-7A5B-34A6-A2EE-2B852E60E1E2> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
    0x7fff8acd4000 -     0x7fff8aceeff7  liblzma.5.dylib (7) <1D03E875-A7C0-3028-814C-3C27F7B7C079> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
    0x7fff8acef000 -     0x7fff8ade1ff7  libiconv.2.dylib (42) <2A06D02F-8B76-3864-8D96-64EF5B40BC6C> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x7fff8ade2000 -     0x7fff8ae77ff7  com.apple.ColorSync (4.9.0 - 4.9.0) <9150C2B7-2E6E-3509-96EA-7B3F959F049E> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ColorSync.framework/Versions/A/ColorSync
    0x7fff8aec6000 -     0x7fff8aedcff7  libsystem_asl.dylib (267) <F153AC5B-0542-356E-88C8-20A62CA704E2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x7fff8b19f000 -     0x7fff8b9faff3  com.apple.CoreGraphics (1.600.0 - 779.11) <EFAB294A-B307-38C5-A3B0-159159B41057> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
    0x7fff8b9fb000 -     0x7fff8ba6fffb  com.apple.securityfoundation (6.0 - 55126) <42589E18-D38C-3E25-B638-6E29740C224C> /System/Library/Frameworks/SecurityFoundation.framework/Versions/A/SecurityFoundation
    0x7fff8baac000 -     0x7fff8bb2afff  com.apple.CoreServices.OSServices (640.4 - 640.4) <20121A5E-7AB5-3624-8CF0-3562F97C8A95> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
    0x7fff8bbf4000 -     0x7fff8c001ff7  libLAPACK.dylib (1128) <F9201AE7-B031-36DB-BCF8-971E994EF7C1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fff8c070000 -     0x7fff8c073fff  com.apple.IOSurface (97.4 - 97.4) <AE11CFBC-4D46-30F3-BEEC-4C8131079391> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Versions/A/IOSurface
    0x7fff8c083000 -     0x7fff8c302ff7  com.apple.CoreData (111 - 526.3) <5A27E0D8-5E5A-335B-B3F6-2601C7B976FA> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
    0x7fff8c303000 -     0x7fff8c305fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib (11.1.2) <6EFEC4A6-2EAC-3C27-820E-C28BE71B9FCB> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
    0x7fff8c35c000 -     0x7fff8c376ff7  libextension.dylib (55.2) <3BB019CA-199A-36AC-AA22-14B562138545> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
    0x7fff8c377000 -     0x7fff8c377fff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.10 - Accelerate 1.10) <F1B96A61-7E4B-31BD-A35B-BA7EF1F16EF4> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff8c3f8000 -     0x7fff8c586fff  libBLAS.dylib (1128) <497912C1-A98E-3281-BED7-E9C751552F61> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fff8c587000 -     0x7fff8c5acff7  libJPEG.dylib (1237) <8AC8EFA6-2283-3725-9F28-01537DF51766> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJPEG.dylib
    0x7fff8c5ad000 -     0x7fff8c5d7ff7  libdispatch.dylib (442.1.4) <502CF32B-669B-3709-8862-08188225E4F0> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x7fff8c5d8000 -     0x7fff8c6cbff7  libJP2.dylib (1237) <A48C29E6-9E9F-3449-B873-160DE8E94008> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libJP2.dylib
    0x7fff8cb34000 -     0x7fff8cb93fff  com.apple.AE (681.2 - 681.2) <181B3B06-2DC6-3E4D-B44A-2551C5E9CF6F> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/AE.framework/Versions/A/AE
    0x7fff8cbe0000 -     0x7fff8cc26ff7  libauto.dylib (186) <A260789B-D4D8-316A-9490-254767B8A5F1> /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
    0x7fff8d073000 -     0x7fff8d075ff7  libsystem_coreservices.dylib (9) <41B7C578-5A53-31C8-A96F-C73E030B0938> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
    0x7fff8d076000 -     0x7fff8d084ff7  com.apple.opengl (11.1.2 - 11.1.2) <864B35BF-1E76-382B-8D5F-38C7282621E6> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
    0x7fff8d085000 -     0x7fff8d08afff  libsystem_stats.dylib (163.20.16) <FBC3F80F-A0FB-3BD6-9A7E-800DE45F092E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
    0x7fff8d0b9000 -     0x7fff8d0f9ff7  libGLImage.dylib (11.1.2) <260A4BF3-DC45-369C-A0CD-B667F9D17179> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLImage.dylib
    0x7fff8d100000 -     0x7fff8d19efff  com.apple.Metadata (10.7.0 - 917.35) <8CBD1D32-4F4B-3F9A-AC65-76F2B5376FBF> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
    0x7fff8d19f000 -     0x7fff8d1caff3  libarchive.2.dylib (30) <8CBB4416-EBE9-3574-8ADC-44655D245F39> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
    0x7fff8d1cb000 -     0x7fff8d1cdfff  libquarantine.dylib (76.20.1) <7AF90041-2768-378A-925A-D83161863642> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
    0x7fff8d3b4000 -     0x7fff8d3e4fff  com.apple.GSS (4.0 - 2.0) <A37BAF76-C262-3292-B82D-F004CAC5F333> /System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/GSS
    0x7fff8d3e5000 -     0x7fff8d64fff7  com.apple.security (7.0 - 57031.20.26) <6568520A-587D-3167-BB79-60CE6FEADC64> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
    0x7fff8d689000 -     0x7fff8d6faffb  com.apple.ApplicationServices.ATS (360 - 375.2) <2338AF23-528F-359A-847F-8B04E49E2B84> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/ATS.framework/Versions/A/ATS
    0x7fff8d78f000 -     0x7fff8d8a6fe7  libvDSP.dylib (516) <DFEDB210-49D1-3803-88A2-C61DB6A45C3D> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvDSP.dylib
    0x7fff8ddd0000 -     0x7fff8dde7ff7  libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1128) <E78CCBAA-A999-3B65-8EC9-06DB15E67C37> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
    0x7fff8ddff000 -     0x7fff8de6dffb  com.apple.Heimdal (4.0 - 2.0) <7697A837-98B8-3BDB-A7D2-8ED4C9ABC510> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Heimdal.framework/Versions/A/Heimdal
    0x7fff8de6e000 -     0x7fff8de70fff  com.apple.loginsupport (1.0 - 1) <DAAD7013-A19D-3858-BFF7-DE1DAF664401> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/login.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/loginsupport.framework/Versions/A/loginsupport
    0x7fff8ee34000 -     0x7fff8eeaafe7  libcorecrypto.dylib (233.1.2) <E1789801-3985-3949-B736-6B3378873301> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x7fff8eedf000 -     0x7fff8ef7ee27  com.apple.AppleJPEG (1.0 - 1) <6627DDD9-A8FE-3968-B23A-B6A29AA3919A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/Versions/A/AppleJPEG
    0x7fff8efa5000 -     0x7fff8efbeff7  com.apple.CFOpenDirectory (10.10 - 187) <790ED527-EFD2-3EA6-8C97-A8C04E96EBA7> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
    0x7fff8f0e9000 -     0x7fff8f116fff  com.apple.CoreVideo (1.8 - 145.1) <18DB07E0-B927-3260-A234-636F298D1917> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
    0x7fff8f275000 -     0x7fff8f279ff7  libGIF.dylib (1237) <0990002D-CA11-325D-A432-3A333F2CC088> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libGIF.dylib
    0x7fff8f319000 -     0x7fff8f344fff  com.apple.DictionaryServices (1.2 - 229) <F03DFAC6-6285-3176-9C6D-7CC50F8CD52A> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/Versions/A/DictionaryServices
    0x7fff8f345000 -     0x7fff8f349fff  libpam.2.dylib (20) <E805398D-9A92-31F8-8005-8DC188BD8B6E> /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib
    0x7fff8f34a000 -     0x7fff8f64cffb  com.apple.GeoServices (1.0 - 1077.0.18) <2BBF8B44-DD46-3432-8C84-6D6AA004C233> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/Versions/A/GeoServices
    0x7fff8f6e0000 -     0x7fff8f6e4fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib (79.1) <201EF6DF-5074-3CB7-A361-398CF957A264> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libCoreVMClient.dylib
    0x7fff8f765000 -     0x7fff8f775ff7  libbsm.0.dylib (34) <A3A2E56C-2B65-37C7-B43A-A1F926E1A0BB> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x7fff8fa05000 -     0x7fff8fa16fff  libcmph.dylib (1) <46EC3997-DB5E-38AE-BBBB-A035A54AD3C0> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
    0x7fff8fa67000 -     0x7fff8fa70fff  libsystem_pthread.dylib (105.10.1) <3103AA7F-3BAE-3673-9649-47FFD7E15C97> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x7fff8fa71000 -     0x7fff8fa7eff7  libbz2.1.0.dylib (36) <2DF83FBC-5C08-39E1-94F5-C28653791B5F> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x7fff8fa7f000 -     0x7fff8facbff7  libcups.2.dylib (408.2) <E8AD18F9-61E4-3791-B840-504468C25556> /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
    0x7fff8fba9000 -     0x7fff8fc6cff7  libvMisc.dylib (516) <21497A28-8DCB-3EB8-BDAC-93C93382B0AA> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libvMisc.dylib
    0x7fff8fc6d000 -     0x7fff8fc7efff  libsystem_coretls.dylib (35.20.2) <6084A531-2523-39F8-B030-811FA1A32FB5> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
    0x7fff8fc7f000 -     0x7fff8fd63fff  libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib (52.20.2) <977DA067-2588-3BF8-A7B2-F08FC6E9088F> /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
    0x7fff8fd94000 -     0x7fff8fdb0ff7  libsystem_malloc.dylib (53.1.1) <19BCC257-5717-3502-A71F-95D65AFA861B> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x7fff909d0000 -     0x7fff909dbfff  libGL.dylib (11.1.2) <BF99CC65-215A-3C7D-87D7-3F7EE6E9B3DD> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGL.dylib
    0x7fff909dc000 -     0x7fff90a0cfff  libsystem_m.dylib (3086.1) <1E12AB45-6D96-36D0-A226-F24D9FB0D9D6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x7fff90a0d000 -     0x7fff90a11fff  libcache.dylib (69) <45E9A2E7-99C4-36B2-BEE3-0C4E11614AD1> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
    0x7fff90a12000 -     0x7fff90a37ff7  libPng.dylib (1237) <CFBF1344-36AB-3AAE-B2EB-9FC1369F967F> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/libPng.dylib
    0x7fff90ab1000 -     0x7fff90cbeff3  com.apple.CFNetwork (720.3.13 - 720.3.13) <69E15385-5784-3912-88F6-03B16F1C1A5C> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    0x7fff910ff000 -     0x7fff910ffff7  libkeymgr.dylib (28) <77845842-DE70-3CC5-BD01-C3D14227CED5> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x7fff911e3000 -     0x7fff911eeff7  com.apple.speech.synthesis.framework (5.3.3 - 5.3.3) <A5640275-E2A6-3856-95EF-5F0DC440B10C> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechSynthesis.framework/Versions/A/SpeechSynthesis
    0x7fff911ef000 -     0x7fff911f2fff  com.apple.xpc.ServiceManagement (1.0 - 1) <9E025823-660A-30C5-A568-223BD595B6F7> /System/Library/Frameworks/ServiceManagement.framework/Versions/A/ServiceManagement
    0x7fff911fb000 -     0x7fff912edfff  libxml2.2.dylib (26) <B834E7C8-EC3E-3382-BC5A-DA38DC4D720C> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x7fff912f4000 -     0x7fff9133eff7  com.apple.HIServices (1.22 - 522.1) <E8BD41E4-7747-3CAF-807A-5CA9AD16B525> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/HIServices
    0x7fff91343000 -     0x7fff9134eff7  com.apple.CrashReporterSupport (10.10 - 631) <D87A64FA-64B1-3B23-BB43-ADE173C108C6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/Versions/A/CrashReporterSupport
    0x7fff91381000 -     0x7fff91381fff  com.apple.ApplicationServices (48 - 48) <5BF7910B-C328-3BF8-BA4F-CE52B574CE01> /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
    0x7fff91816000 -     0x7fff91818fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (358.20.5) <4CF77128-6BE0-3958-B646-707FA9CE61B2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff91819000 -     0x7fff91824ff7  libkxld.dylib (2782.20.48) <28EF8328-E3E2-336A-974B-FB1BF119D55A> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
    0x7fff91825000 -     0x7fff91842fff  com.apple.MultitouchSupport.framework (263.9.1 - 263.9.1) <6ABD3AE2-DF6A-3AB2-994B-9C0FB42CE2B7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
    0x7fff918c8000 -     0x7fff918c8ff7  libunc.dylib (29) <5676F7EA-C1DF-329F-B006-D2C3022B7D70> /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
    0x7fff92d7e000 -     0x7fff92d7eff7  liblaunch.dylib (559.20.9) <FA89A113-696E-3271-8FE1-A0D7324E8481> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x7fff92e05000 -     0x7fff92e06fff  libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (100) <2EE8E436-5CDC-34C5-9959-5BA218D507FB> 
# I had to delet a few lines because it complained that here is too much text ....

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 46959
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=150.3M resident=100.5M(67%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=49.9M(33%)
Writable regions: Total=8456K written=0K(0%) resident=96K(1%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=8360K(99%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
STACK GUARD                        56.0M
Stack                              8192K
VM_ALLOCATE                           8K
__DATA                             7732K
__LINKEDIT                         70.9M
__TEXT                             79.4M
__UNICODE                           552K
shared memory                         4K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             222.4M`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locationd file was corrupted.

After trying to access my privacy settings in safe mode and normal mode (which did not work, it crashed) and after a restart and PRAM reset (which did not help neither) I installed the combo update from here https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1804?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US and that worked very well :)

Comment: Huzzah! Also see this gem for a potential manner to check if your locationd is corrupt and restore a copy.  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/how-can-i-get-back-a-system-file-after-deleting-it-from-my-mac

Answer (score 7):

That process is a diagnostic aid to capture system statistics. The system starts it when it detects a potential problem or an actual problem - so you've likely got something out of adjustment or problematic installed.

It's from Apple and generally is more like a fire suppression system than something that starts the fire. To use that tool to find the initial cause of the CPU usage you'll need a few tools and some basic orientation.

First, open up Console.app and look for the **Show Log List/Hide Log List** button. Press it to expose the User and System Diagnostics Reports.

You can monitor the actual reasons why Report Crash is running here. If there are a lot of events, you can right click a name and **Reveal in Finder** <kbd>⌘</kbd> - <kbd>R</kbd> and delete or watch the log files more easily in Finder.

Once you have a feel for what the diagnostics look like on that Mac, a second console window can watch /var/log/system.log as you work to see what happened right before the Report Crash fires up.

---

Now for your specific crash. Locationd can be cancelled by turning off all network access. I would turn off Bluetooth if you don't need it and turn off WiFi and disconnect any network cables from the Mac.

Then I'd shut it down and restart. Look at the time when you log back in and watch for more crashes. Once the system is stable - turn on one item (Bluetooth or Wifi or connect one network cable) and then wait for a bit.

You can even poke locationd after the reboot by opening the Maps app and requesting your location. It should warn you about needing things turned on, and ignore those for testing.

Comment: there are files created nearly every 5 seconds. I updated my question an copied the content of one of these files

Comment: @Stophface Wow - that would be a huge waste of CPU and battery (if you're not on wall power). I'll edit my answer once I have a look at your details. Also, consider shutting down the Mac and deleting most of the old diagnostic messages. Sometimes the system gets so backed up with that many crashes, that the cycle self-propogates. A reboot ensures we're chasing the original problem and not complications from the ongoing resource hog.

Comment: I rebooted already. The ReportCrash occus instantly again. You want me to delet all the files (.spin, .crash, .diag etc.) from the folder "System Diagnostic Reports"?

Comment: Let's meet in [chat] if you care to have a short back and forth. editing several times and commenting doesn't work very well for refining an issue.

Comment: sure. I come in there!

Comment: That did not do the trick. The Report Crash fires up right after restarting even with all network connections shut down. I cannot even open my privacy settings without causing a crash of the system preferences.

Comment: I cannot even open the privacy and security settings in safe mode. it crashes...

Comment: See my answer. Solved it!

Answer (score 7):

According to the `man` page (`man ReportCrash`):

> launchtl can be used to disable and re-enable crash reporting.  To disable crash reporting:
>
> ```
>       launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.ReportCrash.plist
>       sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.ReportCrash.Root.plist
> ```
>
> To re-enable crash reporting:
>
> ```
>       launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.ReportCrash.plist
>       sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.ReportCrash.Root.plist
> ```

Answer (score 2):

I was googling for a solution. I tried reinstalling OSX. I tried some clean up using the Onyx utility.

In the Console application where you see that something is crashing and restarting and crashing again, you can see some file path in the reports.

So this solution I found somewhere. You can see this path in the Console application when the problem is occurring, so it make sense and works. I also restarted that `locationd` service by running this:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locationd.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locationd.plist
```

Only deleting `/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000sm00006d` fixed this problem in my osx installation.

Comment: HOLYYYYYY CRAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPPPPPPPPPPPP! I HAVE HAD THIS PROBLEM SEVERAL TIMES OVER THE LAST 10 YEARS. THIS IS THE ONLY SOLUTION THAT WORKS... THANKSSSSSSSSS