# Unfortunate deleting binary command file

Tags: unix, macos, command-line

I deleted "`chmod`" by mistake using "`sudo rm chmod`".
What is the way to recover the `chmod` command?
Is it 'a no way to do it' operation?
I'm using Mac OS X Yosemite.

Comment: There's a recovery partition; you may be able to use that.  However, I think the question is more appropriate for [Ask Different](http://apple.stackoverflow.com/) — or possibly [Super User](http://superuser.com/).  Also, if you have Time Machine backups running, you should be able to use that to recover a copy of the file, and then carefully use `sudo` to copy it back to `/bin/chmod`.  And, in future, make sure you are paying attention when you're working as root.  Removing a single binary is fairly innocuous compared with the damage you could have done.

Comment: Thanks to reply. However I didn't have any backups, so i need another way.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/116611/45492) probably has all the answers for you. In short there is no easy way. Your options are:

1. Recover the files from a (Time machin) Backup, if existent.
2. Reinstall OSX, e.g. from the Recovery mode pressing  <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at the startup screen
3. Copy the missing files from the Recovery partition (check if the partition is up to date first). E.g. by doing `cp -a /bin /Volumes/<your disk name>`