# Issues with installing Social Engineering Toolkit (S.E.T)

Tags: macos, homebrew, python

I'm trying to install Social Engineering Toolkit (S.E.T) on OS X Lion.

I found these commands in the internet:
`git clone https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit`

`cd social-engineer-toolkit`

`python setup.py install`

`setoolkit`

But after I do `python setup.py install` it gives me this output:

```
Saffet-iMac:social-engineer-toolkit SaffetYurtoglu$ python3 setup.py install
Searching for pexpect
Best match: pexpect 4.2.0
Adding pexpect 4.2.0 to easy-install.pth file
Using /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Processing dependencies for pexpect
Finished processing dependencies for pexpect
Searching for pycrypto
Best match: pycrypto 2.6.1
Adding pycrypto 2.6.1 to easy-install.pth file
Using /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Processing dependencies for pycrypto
Finished processing dependencies for pycrypto
Searching for pyopenssl
Best match: pyOpenSSL 16.0.0
Adding pyOpenSSL 16.0.0 to easy-install.pth file
Using /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Processing dependencies for pyopenssl
Finished processing dependencies for pyopenssl
Searching for pefile
Best match: pefile 2016.3.28
Adding pefile 2016.3.28 to easy-install.pth file
Using /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Processing dependencies for pefile
Finished processing dependencies for pefile
```

It seems like everything is ok but nothing happens. What should i do?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43397/discussion-on-question-by-john-issues-with-installing-social-engineering-toolkit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here was that there was an error in the $PATH in John's .bash_profile. For some reason, despite removing all the bits about python3.5/3.6 in .bash_profile, the export path command was putting them back in. This was solved by explicitly referencing all the paths and not adding on the current stored $PATH. The install is now using the correct python version.

Answer (score 0):

In a vanilla Lion installing Social Engineering Toolkit works if you use

```
git clone https://github.com/trustedsec/social-engineer-toolkit
cd social-engineer-toolkit
sudo python setup.py install
```

(which will install some necessary tools/libraries to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages).

After "installing" the toolkit use `sudo ./setoolkit` to start the SE Toolkit.

Here are some env variables:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.1
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python -c "import sys;print(sys.path)"
['', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

---

You probably installed Python 3.5 – which is not included in OS X Lion – and modified some env variables. Without further informations your SE Toolkit install can't be salvaged.

Comment: It gave me the same output. I think i installed 3.5 packages too. Should i delete them ?

Comment: What does the "same output" mean? Yours or mine?

Comment: I mean same output as mine. `sudo python setup.py install` gave me the same output. And after that i did the same with python 2.7 and again i got the same but just the version numbers were 2.7 i couldn't copy it here it is too long.

Comment: @John Which Python 3.5 did you install? Homebrew or another installer? Please add a link if you have installed a different one (non-homebrew)! And did you [repair your Lion install](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/247739/deleted-usr-local-bin-and-usr-bin-on-os-x)?

Comment: Yes i reinstalled my mac.I downloaded the python 3.5 from  python.org

Comment: @John I installed Python 3.5.2 additionally and it doesn't interact with the Lion's Python (2.7.1). I didn't change any env variables, bash profiles or system paths after installing Python 3.5.2 though. The SET install works after installing Python 3.5.2 like described above. Strange!

Comment: So do you suggest me anything? I really don't know what to do. It seems like everything is right but nothing is happening , i don't get it. And i just realized that if i do `sudo setup.py` it gives me the same output i don't need to write install to get this return.

Comment: i mean `sudo python setup.py`