# What is the correct ownership for subdirectories in /usr/local

Tags: security, permission, darwin

After a few reckless uses of `chomod` (and some history I don't recall, apparently) I currently have the following ownership in my `/usr/local`:

```
drwxr-xr-x   13 Rax   admin   Caskroom/
drwxr-xr-x   87 Rax   admin   Cellar/
drwxr-xr-x    3 Rax   admin   Frameworks/
drwxr-xr-x   17 Rax   admin   Homebrew/
drwxr-xr-x    2 Rax   admin   Library/
drwxr-xr-x    6 root  wheel   MacGPG2/
drwxr-xr-x  654 Rax   admin   bin/
drwxrwxr-x   16 Rax   admin   etc/
drwxr-xr-x  118 Rax   admin   include/
drwxr-xr-x    4 Rax   admin   info/
drwxr-xr-x  438 Rax   admin   lib/
drwxr-xr-x    3 Rax   admin   libexec/
drwxr-xr-x    5 Rax   admin   man/
drwxr-xr-x    7 Rax   admin   mysql-utilities-1.5.3/
drwxr-xr-x  111 Rax   admin   opt/
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel   remotedesktop/
drwxr-xr-x   42 Rax   admin   share/
drwxr-xr-x   10 Rax   admin   texlive/
drwxr-xr-x    6 Rax   admin   var/
```

Is this the correct default ownership for current (≥ 10.12.5) macOS? Should I change some of these (back) to `root:wheel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box - `root:wheel` has ownership of /usr/local and 0755 permissions. It's really up to you what you want. Since you clearly have homebrew or remnants of that, I'd do whatever `brew doctor` says you need to do for the user account you want to run things. I'd say keeping `user:admin` permissions is just fine for almost all cases in that part of the directory.

I have user:admin and 0775 permissions on everything but `/usr/local` itself and `/usr/local/remotedesktop` which match and are `root:wheel` with 0755.

Comment: So there's no reason to set, for example, `bin` or `etc` to `root:wheel` (and they don't come that way by default)? FWIW, `brew doctor` seems happy with what I've got. An

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Correct - You could open an installer with a tool like Pacifist and see the permissions that the vanilla installer runs or snoop on the recovery HD - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/116612/5472 - if memory serves neither `bin` or `etc` comes out of the box so it's up to whatever process creates them to set permissions or responsible for what permissions you have.

Comment: FWIW, looking at what's on the recovery HD (in what's mounted by `hdiutil mount /Volumes/Recovery\ HD/com.apple.recovery.boot/BaseSystem.dmg`) I see that `bin`, `lib`, `libexec`, `sbin`, `share`, and `standalone` are all present (and all that's present) and all have `Rax:staff`.

Comment: I must admit I'm not clear with the significance of `staff` vs `admin` is here.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius If you mount a dmg you are the owner of the mounted volume and consequently **all** files are RAX:staff - even the mach_kernel! Also: /usr/local doesn't exist in there.

Comment: @klanomath Ah, so what was bmike's point?

Comment: I retract my point in comments about recovery. I’ve looked at the actual installer - /usr/local is the only stock directory and it’s root and wheel - the body of he answer is correct. The comments not so much.