# Default terminal icon accidentally deleted!

Tags: mac, macos, icon

I accidentally deleted my default terminal icon and I also unintentionally replaced the Terminal.icns file in /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Terminal.icns
So can anyone provide me with the original icns file? 
This not a duplicate question the other question is regarding apps not icons and I have deleted the icon not app please red the question carefully

Comment: It is a duplicate, the linked question applies to any system file, including files within apps, and restoring the entire app would solve your problem anyway even though that's not the only solution provided.

Comment: @grgarside But when I was typing in the question ask different didn't showed me that this question already exits and that question has complicated answers unlike this one and even the question is not clear!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you already updated to macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) simply download and re-run the [10.12.6 Combo installer](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1931). One of the subsequent installer packages updates Terminal.app (with the missing Terminal.icns) which will replace your "broken" Terminal.app.

Comment: Reinstalling a combo patch or the full install always is a great option.

Answer (score 4):

To do so would be copyright infringement; however, you could use [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) to extract the files from the Sierra install app.

(disclaimer: I'm the developer of Pacifist)

Comment: This is a great use of your tool - it presents a safe visual for anyone not looking to mount Recovery HD manually to get back parts of the core system without a reinstall. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/116612/5472

Answer (score 3):

You can also opt for grabbing one that looks almost identical imo.

https://thy4205.deviantart.com/art/OS-X-Yosemite-icons-Activity-Monitor-Terminal-458493133

Edit: the comments mention these were extracted from Yosemite, so I guess they are actual apple icons.

Comment: I have copied and pasted in the default icon but the png image is very blurry and doesn't looks like the original one can you please upload the .icns file and png image on this site : https://dbr.ee/ and share the link with me!

Comment: This is the current icon for Sierra, you only need the  .icns  file, here is the link https://dbr.ee/wPse

Comment: It says link/page not found! give me the sharable link