# I need a kext from OS X 10.9.5 (13F1911)

Tags: macos

I really need

`/System/Library/Extensions/IOAHCIFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOAHCIBlockStorage.kext`

It is necessary from OS X 10.9.5 (**13F1911**), that is, with all the latest changes, from just 10.9.5 is not needed.

My request how I can get this Apple software? Re-installing the OS from Recovery is very undesirable, since many valuable files are lost.

In addition, it will be restored from 10.9.5, but not from OS X 10.9.5 (**13F1911**)

[All the methods described here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/how-can-i-get-back-a-system-file-after-deleting-it-from-my-mac) can not solve the problem with the latest Apple updates. Specifically, my system has quite a few modifications I fear I’ll lose.

My English is likely bad here but I'm trying to say that I've spoiled the kext and all recovery methods are not suitable for one simple reason: in the version that I can download from App Store and in versions in /Volumes/Recovery HD/ com.apple.recovery.boot/BaseSystem.dmg updates of the latest releases are not implemented!

(It all happened because I'm trying to implement a patch has not attended to the preservation of the original version, that is that's such bad luck!).

UPD1: I found the required kext inside the "secupd2016-004mavericks.dmg" at the URL: https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1886?locale=en_US[2](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1886?locale=en_US), and **solved the problem!**

UPD2: no simple copying will produce the proper result, you need to implement kext:

```
sudo kextcache -system-prelinked-kernel
sudo kextcache -system-caches
sudo touch /System/Library/Extensions/
reboot
```

Thank you in advance for your help, and sorry for the bad english as I’m not a native writer or speaker.

Another question for the moderator: what does "duplicate" mean? What duplicates my simple request to help me get the the file which I need?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a file on demand service. Re-installing the OS from Recovery will reinstall all the correct kexts.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question. We're all human here and we all try to help, but we can't distribute copyrighted material. If you're having trouble with a specific method of recovering a file or extracting it from an archive or installer, [edit] your question with this specific issue and we can try to assist you in getting the file back on your computer. If you still wish to remove your question, use the delete button underneath.

Comment: Shouldn’t we all upvote questions that are duplicates? That means there is a legitimate question,   Clearly worded, clearly worth an answer and should be featured in search results so everybody can find the main thread where the answers to the questions should go.  I really don’t get the -3 votes on this and thank the person who asked this for their patience while we try to correct the voting misconceptions.

Comment: Hi @cave-canem your English is very good for technical and second language. Can you edit what’s the downside to using recovery to reinstall 10.9 ? My understanding is you get all  the system files back, all the system apps cleanly installed and no user data or preferences or programs lost. It’s literally designed to be the best way to fix a damaged kext. If the answer is to download the security update, please flag this for reopening so you can self answer this.

Comment: Dear @bmike, Thanks for the kind words, but I realize that I have very bad English.I will try to explain it (if I understood you correctly):I have accumulated a huge amount of luggage embedded in the OS (at the system level) changes, and I absolutely do not want to lose it. Any of the seven proposed methods leads to losses. The question was "where to get the file"? Here, when communicating with the moderator, it seemed to me that I was writing a program, and if instead of  `"` I write `'`, the program would not work, which is typical for robots. Once again, forgive my disgusting English!