# Erased /usr/bin/env on accident. How can I restore it?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I accidentally deleted /usr/bin/env and it causing issues when I want to run

```
brew install python
```

I am getting the following error:

```
brew install python3
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 91: /usr/bin/env: No such file or directory
/usr/local/bin/brew: line 91: exec: /usr/bin/env: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

I know this was a mistake, can anyone help me get this file back?

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways to get that file back. It's pretty standard, so you could copy it from a backup or another Mac. You can also just reinstall the OS from recovery and a new system is written and your account and apps all remain intact.

Here is the canonical answer with lots of options:

- [How can I get back a system file after deleting it from my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/116611/how-can-i-get-back-a-system-file-after-deleting-it-from-my-mac)

Answer (score -1):

Running `brew install coreutils` should install the GNU version of `env`.

Comment: That may be true, but it's not going to install it to `/usr/bin/env`